# How to find web developer openings in a specific industry I prefer

Tags: job-search, tech-industry

I'm web dev with 10+ years of experience in web development. I'd like to enter adult industry as a developer. I know I need connections and appropriate companies.

I tried to look around but I couldn't find any good forum or community for that. I saw that PornHub is looking for a web dev but this is the only one I stumbled upon. Is there any source of jobs in adult industry or maybe community that I can join in?

Comment: Why the close votes? This is a legit question for an industry niche

Comment: @VictorS, the question is too broad/ unclear. Questions: "how to get a job as" anything would be too broad.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/56534/employment-in-adult-entertainment-industry-as-a-software-engineer

Comment: @BigMadAndy I see. We can edit the title to avoid the ambiguity, since it is specifically asking about how to find the positions in the first place

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Employment in Adult Entertainment Industry as a Software Engineer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/56534/employment-in-adult-entertainment-industry-as-a-software-engineer)

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure you can check out the company info for any given adult site. Sites for the holding companies usually also have the job postings. Those are just regular web dev jobs really, you should expect nothing tricky besides ordinary business.

Comment: A good answer to a strange question. If anything I would expect possible problems linked to the stigmatization of the industry, especially if OP is in a conservative country, not perks.

Comment: @BigMadAndy: consider that while none of them are Facebook/Google, they typically have a large number of hits and want to work well with a wide range of technologies.  I’d say that someone that came out of the porn industry with a good technical rep, would be a solid hire for just about any organization.